# position fixed margin divs in scrollable content

Tags: css, scroll, position, margin

**Hello**

please have a look at my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJDJP/).

The content of the inner div-element is scrollable.

Each grey symbol has a margin-left. When I scroll the content the symbols shouldn't be fixed to the background.

It should be scrollable with the position.

Have you got an idea how I achieve that effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that positioning is relative to the closest **positioned** parent.

When you are assigning an absolute position to the "symb" class you are positioning them relative to the document rather than their parent.

Simply adding "position: relative;" to your div.tl element will set the parent div as positioned without moving it and the "symb" elements will act the way I think you expect them to.

Your new .tl definition should be:

```
.tl {
    width: 500x;
    height: 80px;
    background-color:grey;
    position: relative;
}
```

Furthermore, I'm assuming that you have some need to position these absolutely. You could achieve similar results by simply removing the "position: absolute" portion of your .symb definition.

You are setting a margin, not a position, so you don't need to bother with positioning at all in your example case.

Comment: That's it. Thanks for the reminder. I will mark it as answered asap.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you need. You had an error in your last "symb" - you missed 'p' in 'px'. Try this?

```
<div class ="outer">
    <div class="inner">
            <div class="tl">
                <div class="box" style="width: 315px;">
                    <div class="symb" style="margin-left: 0px;"></div>
                    <div class="symb" style="margin-left: 15px;"></div>
                    <div class="symb" style="margin-left: 20px;"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.outer {
    width:50%;
}
.inner {
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
.tl {
    width: 500x;
    height: 80px;
    background-color:grey;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    height: 61px;
}

.box .symb {
    float:left;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
position: relative;
```

Not

```
position: absolute;
```

Just try with the following CSS:

```
.box .symb {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    position: inline-block;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```